# Copying pointer values and printing pointers (not the value stored in memory being pointed to)

Tags: c, pointers

I am not sure what i did wrong here.

```
int data[x][y];
int **pointerCopy = (int**) data
printf("%p, %p \n" pointerCopy, data);
```

Since pointercopy copies the pointer that is data, shouldn't the value printed be the same? However it is not.

Comment: I get the same values (after fixing all your syntax errors).

Comment: Same here, equal results.

Comment: `"%p"` is technically only for `void *` pointers, so you do have undefined behavior.  Realistically, that's probably not what's causing your problem, but you haven't provided your output nor a complete, runnable example so we can't really tell.  Also, if you ever tried to access your two-dimensional array `data` using an `int **` such as your `pointerCopy`, it wouldn't work.  Something like `int **pointerCopy` **does not and can not refer to an array**.

Comment: Your program is incomplete and contains at least one syntax error. Please [edit]  your question and provide real code such as a [mcve].

Comment: Another tip, as an extension to @AndrewHenle 's comment: If `data` had been an array of strings (i.e. `char *`) or an multi dim array of a struct, your way of defining the `**pointerCopy` would be more meaningful, but for an array of plain `int`, a `*pointerCopy` with one star will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, after fixing the syntax errors and ignoring the warnings, the output value *is* the same for both pointers.

Here's the code:

```
~/Desktop/PLAYGROUND$ cat aaa.c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x, y;
    x = y = 10;
    int data[x][y];
    int **pointerCopy = (int**) data;
    printf("%p, %p \n" ,pointerCopy, data);
}
```

And this is the output:

```
0x7ffee6e4c4a0, 0x7ffee6e4c4a0
```